# Add -D options in the CPacCKConfig.cmake

Tags: cmake, cpack

I would like to know if when we create a Cpack-NSIS installer WITHOUT CMake, we can add -D options.

For example:

in CMAKE: cmake `-DPRODUCT=MyProduct --build ...`

in CPACK :  `cpack.exe' -DPRODUCT=MyProduct -C Release --config CPackConfig.cmake`

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`cpack /?`

shows you absolutely can use -D, -C and --config options.

Comment: Sorry my question is not very precise. I know I can use -D options. But the docs indicates that -D defines a CPACK variable.  My option is not. I want to use `if(MyProduct)` then  `INSTALL(Files ...)` in the CPackConfig.cmake like I will do it in a CmakeLists but I don't think that it is possible.

Comment: @sovif That is not directly possible because the CMake-language processor used in CPack is not the same as that in CMake - it is a restricted subset more like the "cmake -P" script mode than CMake itself. You cannot do most things relating to actually building or installing, instead it is mostly for setting CPack related variables from possibly running other scripts. You may be able to hack something CMake-like with `execute_process()` or equivalent, but it is probably is not worth it.